# What is a callout in salesforce

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

I am reading about callout, and it is something I don't understand.
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/force_com_dev_beginner/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro

Is it a simple asynchronous call?, Is it a callback? What is the meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Apex callout enables you to tightly integrate your Apex with an external service by making a call to an external Web service or sending a HTTP request from Apex code and then receiving the response. Apex provides integration with Web services that utilize SOAP and WSDL, or HTTP services (RESTful services).

Callouts enable Apex to invoke external web or HTTP services. Apex Web services allow an external application to invoke Apex methods through Web services.

Comment: Could you you also explain HTTP request? For salesforce the external web service must not be locally hosted, like if there is a WCF webservice then where I need to host it?

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question. If your problem is that you can't reach the endpoint is because you have to whitelist it in the "Remote Site Settings", you might have to add yourself to the list